# What is the meaning of the strange `JavaScript: ` label in the inline event handler?

Tags: javascript

In [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742233/how-to-get-a-value-of-an-input-for-a-link) I've seen the line containing

```
onkeyup="JavaScript: TextChange()" onmouseup="JavaScript: TextChange(this)"`
```

What is it used for? I am seeing this for the first time in my life. I mean label `JavaScript:`.

Comment: This is a thing of the (far) past. Now you may ignore the javascript prefix giving the type. Just as you should completely drop inline event handlers.

Comment: Old IEs were using the pseudo protocol to make a distinct between JScript and VBScript in inline event handlers. Nowadays it not used, VBScript support for web pages was dropped in IE11.

Comment: TIL VBScript is still available in IE10

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yup, and also in IE11, but only with file protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) is entirely pointless as there is no loop to `continue` or `break` from.

It's [cargo culting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) the [`javascript:` URL scheme](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/URL_schemes#javascript:_URLs) and has no place in an intrinsic event attribute.

Comment: I think the first versions of IE having some kind of JS (instead of VBScript only) did ask for that language type specification. But... it's old...